# Alerta HTML en Javascript se repite

Tags: javascript, html, condiciones, function, setinterval

tengo un problema con una alarma en html, para que la función comparativa que enciende la variable este funcionando todo el rato la metí en un intervalo a dos segundos, el problema que tengo ahora es que si se cumple la condición, cada dos segundos te salta otra alarma y no las puedes cerrar del todo hasta que solucionas el problema. Mi idea es que salga una vez como aviso y luego no vuelva a salir, pero la detecte al instante. Os dejo el código por si me podeis echar una mano.

```
setInterval(()=>{
      alarma();
}, 2000)

function alarma(){
  if(bAlarm==true){
    window.alert("Se ha activado la alarma bAlarm")
  }
}
```

Añado que bAlarm es una variable que se pone en true mediante la comunicación con un PLC cuando se activa una entrada de este. No se si es relevante pero lo comento

Comment: Donde haces el `setInterval` cambialo por `const intervalId = setInterval(...`. Luego antes del `alert` pones `clearInterval(intervalId);`. De esa manera desactivarás el intervalo y ya no se volverá a mostrar la alarma.

Comment: Otra opción si solo lo vas a usar una vez, es usar `setTimeout` en lugar de setInterval. Solo se ejecuta una vez cuando pase el tiempo que indicaste. Quedaría asi: `setTimeout(()=>{alarma();}, 2000)`

Answer (score 1):

Pues hacer como te han dicho los compañeros o en la función alarma(), tal que así:

```
function alarma(){
  if(bAlarm==true){
    window.alert("Se ha activado la alarma bAlarm");
    bAlarm = false;
  }
```

Así solo entra en la condición una vez y esta se desactiva al lanzar el alert. Luego no se como la vuelves a poner en true en tu código ya que no aportas más código, pero así se desactivaría.